# How to set a conditional breakpoint on polymorphic type in vs2013?

Tags: c++, mfc, visual-studio-debugging

I have a polymorphic type that I need to output a breakpoint message on based on:

1. if it is of a particular type and
2. if it is that type, that a member of that type has a particular value

If you are interested, the breakpoint is located in `BOOL CCmdUI::DoUpdate(CCmdTarget* pTarget, BOOL bDisableIfNoHndler)` located in `cmdtarg.cpp` of the MFC library.  I want to output a message when `Enable(bHandler)` is called iff the conditions are met.

I've attempted to do a condition like:

```
dynamic_cast<className*>(this) ? ((dllName.dll!className*)this)->m_var == target : 0
```

but I get a the following error message:

> The breakpoint cannot be set. identifier "className" is undefined

This is probably due to the fact that the className is taken from a dll.  So I changed to this:

```
dynamic_cast<dllName.dll!className*>(this) ? ((dllName.dll!className*)this)->m_var == target : 0
```

then I get this error message:

> The breakpoint cannot be set. the operand of a runtime dyanmic_cast must have a polymorphic class type.

The type is polymorphic.  I can see the vtable and it has 4 virtual functions in it.

Just casting it blindly will cause a failure when it is not the type that I am interested in, so what am I to do?

Comment: Instead of the `dynamic_cast`, have you tried setting a breakpoint on the concrete derived type? If the that method is unavailable you can use the [Context Operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wztycb7f%28VS.80%29.aspx) to set the breakpoint.

Comment: @IInspectable, not sure what you mean by setting on the concrete derived type. Do you have an example?  Also, not sure how the context operator will help.  Example?

Comment: As I understand the question, you are looking for a way to set a breakpoint on `DoUpdate` for `CCmdUI`-derived objects of type `className`. So instead of setting a breakpoint on the base class and filtering on a `dynamic_cast` expression, I suggested to set a breakpoint on the actual derived class (even if it doesn't override the method). The breakpoint syntax is `{,,dllName.dll}<decorated symbol of class member>`, for 32-bit code. I don't know how this would look for 64-bit code, though, as I believe it doesn't use decorated names.